# Obtaining a list of fonts ready to be used in TeX/Latex

Tags: fonts, tex-core

How can I obtain a list of fonts that I can use in `Plain TeX` and `LaTeX` through the command prompt in Windows/Linux?

Is it possible to use them without loading a package in `LaTeX`?

Comment: do you mean fonts available in pdftex (just do a directory listing of temf-dist/fonts) or fonts available in xetex or luatex which includes all those plus any opentype/truetype fonts installed in the operating system

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am actually following the tutorial `A Gentle Introduction to Tex` so I am interested in fonts compatible with `pdftex/pdflatex`  and regular `tex/latex` engines with dvi output. Also using fonts that are not readily available seems to be confusing. Do I always have to use packages in `LaTeX` for changing fonts (apart from Luatex and Xetex) ?

Comment: you don't have to use a package, but why not? Certainly for math, when setting up a full set of compatible math fonts takes many declarations, loading a package where someone has already written the necessary code  is far easier. there is an existing answer with an indication of the list (thousands of fonts) I'll see if I can find...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on the commandline

```
kpsewhich -all ls-R
```

lists all the pre-hashed files found by kpathsea so (using bash syntax)

```
grep '[.]tfm'  `kpsewhich -all ls-R`
```

will list all the tfm files available in your texlive.

I won't list them here as (using texlive 2017 pretest)

```
$ grep '[.]tfm'  `kpsewhich -all ls-R` | wc -l
42740
```

so over 40 thousand font metric files that may be loaded into tex.