# Fonts and options

Tags: fonts

Can I get a list of all available fonts in my system (MikTeX) ? I downloaded an old Egyptian type font, and I was also wondering if I could put it as the font for all Chapters and Section headers, and a different font for the body. Is it possible?

Comment: see this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368044/obtaining-a-list-of-fonts-ready-to-be-used-in-tex-latex/368048#368048  which shows there around 40 thousand fonts distributed with tex, then if you use xelatex or lualatex you can in addition use any of the truetype or opentype fonts installed in Windows.

Comment: You can include formatting commands in \chpatername; e.g. \renewcommand{\chaptername}{\textit{Chapter}}.  Presumably this will work for font changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### List of all fonts

To get a list of all fonts was a good idea some years ago. Today, in the year 2017, the `getnonfreefonts` command will get you a bunch of new fonts on your harddrive and inspecting the font catalogue at CTAN is like swimming in the ocean.

You can install thousands of fonts, using the package manager of MiKTeX.

### Using different fonts

It is possible to use a certain fonts for the chapter headings, another one for the section headings and a third one for the text.

How you do this depends on the documentclass you use. With a KOMAscript documentclass you'd write something like `\addtokomafont{chapter}{...}`, with memoir somethink completly different.

Furthermore it depends on the »engine«, e.g. pdfTeX, XeTeX or LuaTeX. I can't give any advice, because I even don't know in which language you are writing. Is it right to left, left to right or both?

Please read an introduction into LaTeX. If you need the manual of a package, type on the command line: `texdoc packagename` (packagename = the name of the package), e.g. `texdoc latex` or `texdoc geometry`.